# Change the limit of rows in a Footable table?

Tags: jquery, footable

I am doing a query in postgresql that retuns me more than 160 registers. When I try to put the data into a footable table, it only shows 10 rows and nothing more.
I tried to add the property in table tag called data-page-size="10000" or data-paging-size="10000" with no luck.

I don't want to put several pages, I just want one page with all the registers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
var numberOfRows = 20;

$('.footable').footable();        
$('.footable').data('page-size', numberOfRows);
$('.footable').trigger('footable_initialized');
```

OR set the table attribute data-paging-size="20"

```
<table class="footable" data-paging-size="15">
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the attribute format you want to use:

```
data-paging-size="1000"
```

However, it sounds like you want to turn paging off, which you can do during initialization by **not** including `"paging": {"enabled": true}` when initializing footable:

```
// document ready
$(function () {
    $('#myTable').footable({
        // initialization options
    });
});
```

10 is the default page size. [Source](http://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/components/paging.html#size)

Answer (score 1):

try it

```
$(id).footable({pageSize:50});
```

I find pageSize argument in footable source
and it's seem work